# Vlookup with Concatination between two dates

Tags: excel, vlookup

I'm trying to do a Vlookup with a concatenation between two dates.

For example, if I have an event (Apple, Orange, 4/27/2017) and I want to see if there is any concatenation (Apple, Orange, "date") in another sheet that falls between 4/27/2017 and 4/1/2017, how would I go about doing this? Also, if there are multiple Apple, Orange concatenations with dates between 4/27/2017 and 4/1/2017, how do I make sure it picks up the Apple & Orange & date concatenation that is the closest date to 4/27/2017?

Comment: This is barely possible using worksheet functions and requires a hard-coded date range. A VBA sub procedure or a VBA UDF is probably better.

Comment: Apple and Orange are in the same column?

Comment: if you show an example of your Data, screenshot it will help maybe Countifs instead of Vlookup?

Comment: Thanks for the help, I think I figured it out!